# Why am I getting Server Error in '/' Application in IIS?

Tags: iis

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> The resource cannot be found.
>
> Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its
> dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is
> temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make
> sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /Account/Examples/fio.aspx
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
> ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.18044

This  page I am trying to assess is here now:

```
 http://localhost/<mysitename>/Account/Examples/fio.aspx
```

but when I was writing and debugging site in Visual Studio ,everything worked fine and my page was here

> /Account/Examples/fio.aspx

Since this morning. I have no idea how to fix it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the below code to your web.config file. Your browser will then show you the full error message.

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I suppose my mistake was clear without any other informationfrom browser. But thanks anyway I will know how to enable it in the future))))

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an application in IIS for you website that points to the root directory of the site as it is deployed on the server. You will also need to create an Application Pool that is set to .Net Framework 4 to manage the IIS process that your site will run as.

You're getting the error because the default website in IIS (usually set to c:\inetpub\wwwroot) doesn't know anything about the pages within your website.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. I managed to solve the problem by goinng to <mysitename> in IIS-> actions -> settings and just set physycal application path from %SystemDrive%\inetpub\wwwroot\ to %SystemDrive%\inetpub\wwwroot\<mysitename> and it worked. However I did it while configuring what you mean by "points to the root directory of the site as it is deployed on the server"  is it the same wha i did?

Comment: Yes. You've gone the other way and changed the default website to point at your app. That's fine until you want to host a 2nd site on the server. Then you'll need to create an application in IIS